# remove italics in latex subscript in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I would like to remove the italics font that appears when I use subscripts in labels. For example, the "Teff" in the x-label has "eff" in italics. I would like latex not render it in such a way. Generally, in latex this can be achieved with the \rm{} command. However, that does not work in matplotlib. Please help.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10)
y = x

plt.plot(x,y,'ro')
plt.xlabel('Primary T$_{eff}$')
```

[image]

Comment: ``\rm`` works for me. Just to be sure, are you escaping the backslash?

Comment: Are you using p3k?  Escaping is going to get nasty.  You might need to do `'\\rm{eff}'`.

Comment: I would suggest using `$T_{\mathrm{eff}}$`, unless `T` is used in text mode within your document.

Comment: \mathrm did the job for me. No, I am using Python 2.7. Thanks a lot all of you!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I have encountered this problem many times and it can be solved with this trick

```
plt.xlabel(r'Primary T$_{\rm eff}$')
```

Comment: In LaTeX2e the `\rm` command is deprecated, and should not be used.

Comment: 'Primary T$_\mathrm{eff}$' also works if you are worried about deprecation.