# Non-italicized Latex font in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a matplotlib plot where on of the x-axis labels has math type in it that I used LaTeX to create.  The problem is that the font is italicized and I need it to match the font of the previous text (non-italicized).  The code looks as follows:

```
par2.set_xlabel("Flux ($neutrons/cm^2s)" , fontsize=26 , labelpad = 20)
```

I found another related ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671659/remove-italics-in-latex-subscript-in-matplotlib)) question where they suggested adding a \rm and tried the following from it:

```
plt.xlabel(r'Primary T$_{\rm eff}$')
```

So that my code would look like:

```
par2.set_xlabel("Flux ($\rmneutrons/cm^2s)" , fontsize=26 , labelpad = 20)
```

But all that does is add an 'm' in front of neutrons

How can I get the font non-italicized so that it matches everything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `r"Flux, $\mathrm{neutrons} / \mathrm{cm}^2$"`.

By the way, this is nothing to do with matplotlib, this is a pure TeX issue. 
The only python-specific thing here is the need to use a raw string, `r"notice the r before the quotation mark"`.

Comment: Thanks! This makes much more sense.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. This solution basically forces the user to manually make all text appearing in a plot the same by applying a TeX font. The REAL solution should involve changing the default font used by TeX to match the one default font used by matplotlib.