# Remove italics in latex subscript symbol in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, latex, italics

I am trying to remove italics font from a latex symbol in a matplotlib plot.
I tried `\mathrm{/copyright}` from the following post, but it seems to not work with symbols:
[remove italics in latex subscript in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671659/remove-italics-in-latex-subscript-in-matplotlib)

Please help!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10)
y = x

plt.plot(x,y,'ro')
plt.xlabel("$\mathrm{\copyright}$")
```

[image]

Comment: You don't have any subscript text in your label; and I don't see anything italicised. What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Also, I believe `\copyright` is available in normal `TeX` text mode, rather than mathmode, so removing the `$$` might help

Comment: You could also directly copy-paste the UTF-8 symbol, without involving TeX. `©` (`plt.title('\u00A9', size=20)` or just `plt.title('©', size=20)`).

Comment: Thank you for the tips. It still looks the same. Maybe there is not a way to display the copyright symbol without the 'c' touching the circle around it...

Comment: Ah, so the problem isn't that it is italic or subscript, but that the "c" touches the circle. This sounds like a classic [X-Y problem](https://xyproblem.info)! Perhaps try changing the font to one which has a copyright symbol that you like the look of?